# How can I remove a Squish event handler?

Tags: python, qt, automated-tests, squish

We're using [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/) for our automated GUI testing.  It's pretty cool - connects directly to Qt objects, is scriptable in Python, [etc.](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/features.php)  I've installed an eventhandler for error dialogs using [their API](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/4.2/ugs-eventhandlers.html).  How do I remove the event handler later?  Is that even possible?

Comment: This _should_ have the label "squish," but that label doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API for removing event handlers. Right now, they are removed when the application terminates. There is a Feature request open in froglogic's task tracker for this though (SQUISH-2663), you could mention that ticket ID in a feature request to squish@froglogic.com to raise the priority of that feature.

Comment: Thanks.  I've sent Froglogic a message.